# Не могу поменять размер изображения HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, img

Всем привет, есть верстка, пытаюсь менять размер изображения по ширине, но либо изображение очень тонкое, либо текст налезает на изображение. Что делать? Заранее спасибо.

```css
.description-container{
 width: 75%;
 display: flex;
}
.img-block{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.img-ud{
 display: flex;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.img-ud img{
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="description-container">
        <div class="img-block">
            <div class="img-ud">
                <img src="http://i5.otzovik.com/2016/02/20/2999864/img/22859706.jpeg" alt="">
                <img src="http://i5.otzovik.com/2016/02/20/2999864/img/22859706.jpeg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="img-ud">
                <img src="http://i5.otzovik.com/2016/02/20/2999864/img/22859706.jpeg" alt="">
                <img src="http://i5.otzovik.com/2016/02/20/2999864/img/22859706.jpeg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="desc-block">
            <div class="contact">
                <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam laudantium adipisci placeat maiores, beatae cupiditate ut quidem voluptates asperiores tempora saepe dolorum fugiat aspernatur quo, recusandae quibusdam doloremque, hic dignissimos!</a>
                <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias laborum similique rem autem sed minima excepturi? Voluptas quis sapiente quos nihil culpa officia esse tenetur, eaque ipsam vel quaerat suscipit.</a>
                <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt distinctio at a sit commodi quasi provident laudantium fugit voluptates eos, repellendus, magnam inventore accusantium ratione dolor iusto ipsum doloremque nemo.</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="map"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: как это выглядеть должно в итоге?

Comment: @websnap примерно так https://imgur.com/a/vBiuY3G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы нормально поменять размер изображения без искажения попробуй прописать аргумент widht="" в теге img, а в кавычках задай размер. Например: img src="" width="150"

Comment: не вариант, т.к. не очень получается, попробуй сам

Answer (score 0):

Изображению в CSS, прописываешь:
width:нужное тебе количество пикселей;
height:нужное тебе количество пикселей;

Comment: а как же адаптация? или для каждого пикселя делать media запрос?